# How to translate week names to locale week names in FullCalendar?

Tags: javascript, html, css, fullcalendar, momentjs

Default language is English. For example French is supported language but Azerbaijani is not. How can I manually change week names. Monday - Bazar ertəsi etc.

Comment: You can override the day name in an array (inside fullcalendar config) - https://fullcalendar.io/docs/v3/dayNames

Comment: It should be noted that the option mentioned in the comment above only applies to older versions of fullcalendar. Newer versions use the built-in internationalisation functionality in JavaScript...so essentially what you get depends on the locale set in your browser, and what it supports. You can still use the `locale` option in fullCalendar to set other fullCalendar-specific data to a particular language.

Comment: Yes dayNames is not working now. And browser locale option doesn't support Azerbaijani unfortunately.